# Intercepting messages emitted from socket server in Nestjs

Tags: socket.io, nestjs

I'm using Socket.io with NestJS Socket Gateways. I am having an issue in implementing interceptors for sockets.

According to [NestJS Gateway Interceptors](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/interceptors) docs, interceptors can be implemented in same way as implementing on any other controller. This thing also works if, in socket gateways, you return the data from same method where you listened the event. Example:

```
// Interceptor will run in this case

@SubscribeMessage("IncomingEvent")
@UseInterceptors(SomeInterceptor)
public handler(socket: Socket) {
    return "dummyStringData";
}
```

But if you use socket server to to emit any messages to connected clients, then it won't work. Example:

```
// Interceptor will not run in this case
@WebSocketGateway()
class SomeGateway {
    @Server
    private socketServer: Server;

    @SubscribeMessage("AnotherIncomingEvent")
    @UseInterceptors(SomeInterceptor)
    public anotherHandler(socket: Socket) {
        this.socketServer.to(socket.id).emit("OutgoingEvent");
    }
}
```

This makes sense too, as I'm using `socketServer` to emit the messages to client (which is pure Socket.io thing).

But my concern is whether there is a way to intercept the messages outgoing to other clients emitted by the server.

I don't know whether I should place this in Socket.io category or NestJS category. So I'm putting it in both. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)